# MIPS Programming Implementing Loop For Any Given Number

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I need to find a solution on how to implement a loop using an entered number as iteration count:

Changes have been made to the code:

```
.data

num1:     .asciiz "\nEnter the first number: "
num2:      .asciiz "\nEnter the second number: "
num3:      .asciiz "\nEnter the third number: "
space: .asciiz ", "
Median: .asciiz " \nThe Median is : "

.text

main:
# Print the prompt to enter the first number
li $v0,4
la $a0, num1
syscall

# Entering the first number
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t2,$v0

# Print the prompt to enter the second number
li $v0,4
la $a0, num2
syscall

# Entering the first number
li $v0,5
syscall
move $t3,$v0

#print the prompt for the third number
li $v0, 4
la $a0, num3
syscall

# Entering the third number 
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t5,$v0

# The if statement or conditional statement
bgt $t2,$t3, bigger
move $t4,$t3
bgt $t4,$t5, bigger1
move $t6,$t5


b endif

bigger:
move $t4,$t2

bigger1:
move $t6,$t4

sub $t7,$t6,$t4
syscall

endif:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Median
syscall

li $v0,1
move $a0,$t7
syscall

#END OF PROGRAM 
li $v0,10
syscall
```

For example, when 40 is entered, then the program will give all the odd numbers from 1 - 40.

Can someone also tell me how to get the median. The output for the median is always 0.

Thanks

Comment: You're never prompting the user for a number in your code.

Comment: @Michael Hi the code has been modified